# Не могу понять как сделать так что бы при использовании JFileChooser не загружается в чат файл

Tags: java, swing, chat

Не могу сделать загрузку файла в поле набора сообщения для отправки. Суть в том что уже реализована кнопка JButton c методом JFileChooser. Кто знает как можно сделать метод-view что бы при открытии с помощью JFileChooser любой файл отобразился в поле написания смс-сообщения?

```
re.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {   
         JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();    
         fileopen.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);    
         FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("MPEG3 songs", "mp3");   
         fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
         fileopen.showOpenDialog(null); 
         fileopen.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES); 
         int ret = fileopen.showOpenDialog(fileopen);       
         if(ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){        
             File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();        
             labl.setText(file.getName());         
             fileopen.setVisible(true);
         }       
     }
});
```

Это реализована кнопка "Прикрепить файл". Но при нажатии на нее открывается `JFileChooser` отдельное окно в который похож на проводник. И нажимая открыть файл окно закрывается и ничего не происходит, файл не отображается. Перепробовал все что мог. Ребят помогите кто знает как решить эту проблему?Буду очень благодарен.